# Delete lines of many files using grep and GNU parallel

Tags: grep, gnu-parallel

I have a directory with many files that all end in "_all.txt". I want to delete all lines in each of these files containing either a "*" or a "-" and send them to files ending in "_all_cleaned.txt".

Right now I am using a for loop as follows:

```
for file in *_all.txt;
do
filename=$(echo $file | cut -d '_' -f 1)
grep -vwE "(*|-)" ${file}> "${filename}_all_cleaned.txt"
done
```

I would like to be able to do this in parallel using GNU parallel so that the command will be executed on each file on a different compute node instead of waiting for one node to do all in a row.

How can I incorporate

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the login dir on the servers (i.e. the dir you get by `ssh server1 pwd`):

```
parallel -Sserver1,server2 'grep -vwE "(*|-)" {} > {=s/.txt$/_cleaned.txt=}' ::: *.txt
```

If it is the same dir relative to `$HOME` (e.g. `/home/me/my/dir`):

```
parallel --wd . -Sserver1,server2 'grep -vwE "(*|-)" {} > {=s/.txt$/_cleaned.txt=}' ::: *.txt
```

If it is `/different/dir`:

```
parallel --wd /different/dir -Sserver1,server2 'grep -vwE "(*|-)" {} > {=s/.txt$/_cleaned.txt=}' ::: *.txt
```